# Elegant way to disconnect slot after first call

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

Inside the constructor, there is a connection:

```
connect(&amskspace::on_board_computer_model::self(),
      SIGNAL(camera_status_changed(const amskspace::camera_status_t&)),
      this,
      SLOT(set_camera_status(const amskspace::camera_status_t&)));
```

And the method:

```
void camera_model::
set_camera_status(const amskspace::camera_status_t& status) {
  disconnect(&amskspace::on_board_computer_model::self(),
             SIGNAL(camera_status_changed(const amskspace::camera_status_t&)),
             this,
             SLOT(set_camera_status(const amskspace::camera_status_t&)));

  // do the job
}
```

And I'd like to disconnect this slot after the first call.

The question is: Is there a way to call the slot only once? Without the explicit disconnection? Like a single shot method? Is it possible?

Comment: What is the problem with using `disconnect()` function?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `disconnect`? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Just to know if there is another way. For some developers, Call the disonnect after first calling is annoying, and I'd like to know if there is a way to do it.

Comment: I have a solution for a signal/slot without arguments, I'll try to find a solution for any arguments tomorrow. Do you have C++11/Qt5?

Comment: Actually my environment is a linux with C++ 4.4.7, and Qt4.8. But incoming solutions are welcome, also in Windows/C++11./Qt5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The core idea is to create a wrapper, a special "connect" which automatically disconnect the signal. This is usefull if you use a lot of "call me once" connections; otherwise I'd advice a Qobject::disconnect at the beginning of the slot.

This implementation works by creating 2 connections: a "normal" one, and one that disconnect & cleanup everything just after.

**An implementation (using C++11/Qt 5, ):**

```
template <typename Func1, typename Func2>
static inline QMetaObject::Connection weakConnect(
        typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal,
        typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::Object *receiver, Func2 slot)
{

    QMetaObject::Connection conn_normal = QObject::connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot);

    QMetaObject::Connection* conn_delete = new QMetaObject::Connection();

    *conn_delete = QObject::connect(sender, signal, [conn_normal, conn_delete](){
        QObject::disconnect(conn_normal);
        QObject::disconnect(*conn_delete);
        delete conn_delete;
    });
    return conn_normal;
}
```

**Caveats/Things to improve:**

- the cleanup occurs **after** calling the regular slot. If the regular slot causes the signal to be emitted again, the regular slot will be executed again (potentially causing an infinite recursion).
- no proper way to disconnect, except by emitting the signal. (you can use `QObject::disconnect`, but that would cause a small memory leak)
- relies on the order of execution of slots. Seems fine for now.
- the naming

**Tested using:**

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void sig(int a);
};


class B : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    B(int b) : QObject(), b_(b) {}
    int b() const { return b_; }
public slots:
    void slo(int a) { qDebug() << "\tB :" << b_ << "a:" << a;  }
private:
    int b_;
};
```

and

```
A a1;
A a2;

B b10(10);
B b20(20);

weakConnect(&a1, &A::sig, &b10, &B::slo);
weakConnect(&a1, &A::sig, &b20, &B::slo);
weakConnect(&a2, &A::sig, &b20, &B::slo);

qDebug() << "a1 :"; emit a1.sig(1);// Should trigger b10 and b20 slo
qDebug() << "a2 :"; emit a2.sig(2);// Should trigger b20 slo
qDebug() << "a1 :"; emit a1.sig(3);// Should do nothing
qDebug() << "a2 :"; emit a2.sig(4);// Should do nothing
```

Test code output:

```
a1 :
    B : 10 a: 1
    B : 20 a: 1
a2 :
    B : 20 a: 2
a1 :
a2 :
```

**Getting rid of C++11/Qt5** (I don't have Qt 4.8/GCC4.4.7, so not tested with those)
According to the doc, Qt 4.8 doesn't have a connect to function, so I'm using a wrapper:

```
class ConnectJanitor : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void cleanup()
    {
        QObject::disconnect(conn_normal_);
        QObject::disconnect(*conn_delete_);
        delete conn_delete_;
        delete this;
    }
public:
    static ConnectJanitor* make(QMetaObject::Connection conn_normal,
                                QMetaObject::Connection* conn_delete)
    {
        return new ConnectJanitor(conn_normal, conn_delete);
    }
private:
    ConnectJanitor(QMetaObject::Connection conn_normal,
                   QMetaObject::Connection* conn_delete) :
        QObject(0) , conn_normal_(conn_normal), conn_delete_(conn_delete) {}

    ConnectJanitor(const ConnectJanitor&); // not implemented
    ConnectJanitor& operator=(ConnectJanitor const&);


    QMetaObject::Connection conn_normal_;
    QMetaObject::Connection* conn_delete_;
};
```

(I'm making the `ConnectJanitor`'s constructor private because the instance self-destructs (`delete this`))

and for `weakConnect`:

```
static inline QMetaObject::Connection weakConnect(const QObject * sender, const char * signal, const QObject * receiver, const char * slot)
{
    QMetaObject::Connection conn_normal = QObject::connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot);
    QMetaObject::Connection* conn_delete = new QMetaObject::Connection();
    *conn_delete = QObject::connect(sender, signal, ConnectJanitor::make(conn_normal, conn_delete), SLOT(cleanup()));
    return conn_normal;
}
```

If you need to manually break the connections, I suggest to have weakConnect() returning the ConnectJanitor's pointer.